# Data transfer between 2 data models using a single tableview with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two data models. One for to-do items, one for completed items. In both model, it only need the content of the items and a flag if it is completed. Here are the codes:
For to-do items:

```
class TodoList: NSObject {
    var task: String
    var completed: Bool

    init(task: String) {
        self.task = task
        self.completed = false
    }
}
```

For completed items:

```
class CompletedList: NSObject {
    var task: String
    var completed: Bool

    init(task: String) {
        self.task = task
        self.completed = true
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is, when the item in to-do list is marked completed, it will be removed from to-do item model and move/copy to completed item model.  How can I get this to work? Thanks.

PS: these two data models will be sharing a single table view with  segmented control.

**EDIT:**
Maybe my previous statement is confusing. Let me rephrase it:
I setup a UITableView with Segmented Control.
The Segmented Control has two segments, "To-do" & "Done".
When "To-do" is selected, the table view will display the list of item that is NOT completed. When "Done" is selected, the table view will display the list of item that is completed.
What's the best practice for achieving this?

Comment: You have it backwards. The two data models will not be sharing the same table view. Data models must not know anything about any views. The view needs to know about the data model. So the table view will be using both data models (through the table view's `dataSource`.

Comment: Thanks. I know that models must not know the view. How can I set it up in the View controller to pass the completed item from to-do list to completed list?

Comment: I store all sorts of information in custom UITableViewCells because I know it will following the cell around for the lifetime of the cell.

Comment: @Larcerax I setup the model with a BOOL value. But I don't know how to display it. Could you show me how to achieve this with just one data model? Thanks.

Comment: This assumes you know how to toss arrays back and forth with UITableViews, but this is a terrible task to try to to do, so I avoid all of this and use Voided block methods as properties on custom cells and then capture the touch events that way, it then becomes something you control entirely through the cusotm cell object.

Comment: @Larcerax - I don't quite understand why you freely admit that storing this data in `UITableViewCell` is "terrible" (and you're absolutely right; it is a horrible way to do this, antithetical to key design concepts of MVC, reusable cells, etc.), but then proceed to to advise f_qi how to do this.

Comment: the user asked for it, so I gave it, that's why, @Rob,

Comment: I use this blocking method all the time, but not for model manipulation like this

Comment: @Larcerax I appreciate your intent, but I'll respectfully disagree, because I don't see f_qi ever asking how to store model data in `UITableViewCell`, and if he did, we'd outline all the reasons why one would not do that. But hopefully he'll see these comments and realize that this is not the way to proceed.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, I'll recscind my comments because it's going to create a nightmare for all of us in the future if this gets out in the wild more than it already is, it's okay to use blocking functions like I do for surface level push events, but this can get out of control very quickly and we would then have some very confused coders here

Comment: @f_qi there's a better way to do this, I'll try to have something more coder friendly ASAP to make up for the confusion, the only issue you'll have is that touch events and "cell selection" doesn't work very well with resusable cells or when table views are used in UIViewControllers, anyway, let me think about this, in the mean time if someone shoots you the answer, then excellent!

Comment: Thanks @Larcerax, Rob. After reading all your comments and the example provided. I'm confused. All I wanted to achieve is, I have a tableView setup with segmented control. When I click the segmented control, it will switch between to-do list(not completed) and completed list. I'll try to rephrase my question in a better way.

Comment: You could rephrase more, but it's okay, the way this can be done, well just off the top of my head is in your tableView information array ( the array you use to populate the table) you could store the model next to the array data such that you have a 2 demensiona array, when when the trigger is flipped in the cell saying "this task is complete' you call to the second dimension of the array and set the property, something like this tableViewarray[indexPath.row][isWhateverCompleted] = true; this is theoretical, in the sense of "can an object's values change in a immutable array"

Comment: cotinued .. as long as the value of the array cells themself don't change, that's something I don't know, but your question is clear, I just don't know if you can use a 2 dimensional immutable array where you are free to "set" the underlying objects without disrupting the immutability. I've never attempted to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of reactions:

1. Your class names suggest these represent lists of tasks, but the implementations (namely a task description and completed state) suggest these classes represent individual tasks. I'd suggest you clarify your model, possibly having separate classes for these two types of entities (individual tasks vs collections of tasks).
2. I'd suggest a single `Task` class. The only question is then how you capture the `todo` vs `complete` state:

   - You could represent the completed state merely as a property of the `Task`:

     ```
     class Task {
         var title: String
         var completed: Bool

         init(title: String, completed: Bool = false) {
             self.title = title
             self.completed = completed
         }
     }
     ```

     Then, you could have a collection of all of the tasks:

     ```
     var tasks = [Task]()
     ```

     Then, when you want a list of the completed tasks, you could:

     ```
     let completed = tasks.filter() { $0.completed }
     ```

     Or, likewise, the list of todos:

     ```
     let todo = tasks.filter { !$0.completed }
     ```

     This sort of implementation is impractical if you have very long lists, but for a simple list of issues, it's an easy approach.
   - Alternatively, you can simplify the task class, removing the `completed` state:

     ```
     class Task {
         var title: String

         init(title: String) {
             self.title = title
         }
     }
     ```

     But then maintain collections of tasks (either arrays or sets or whatever makes sense for your app):

     ```
     var todo = [Task]()
     var completed = [Task]()
     ```

     And then, when you want to move an item from the todo list to the completed list, you simply remove it from one and add it to the other.

     ```
     func completeTodoTaskAtIndex(index: Int) {
         if index < todo.count {
             let task = todo[index]
             todo.removeAtIndex(index)
             completed.append(task)
         }
     }
     ```

Once you figure out the appropriate model for your app, then having the tableview show the results properly is pretty easy. So nail down the model first, and the rest will follow logically from that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter about data models. As these are not related to your view. You have to set the data which will be presented to the tableview.

> these two data models will be sharing a single table view with
>   segmented control.

You can set this from tableView delegates. like:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0
        return toDoTask.count
    else
        return completedTask.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    //Check the section and return data if it is completed or incomplete
    return cell
}
```